# "GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=34" error in electron.js on scrolling paginated page on Windows 10

Tags: electron, gpu, chromium, hardware-acceleration

I have a [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/)(version 15.1.1) app which works fine on MacOS but on Windows 10. It become full black when I scroll down when more items loads via REST API call in paginated page.

Exact error is

```
[11668:1006/200834.224:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=34
[11668:1006/200834.225:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(328)] GPU state invalid after WaitForGetOffsetInRange.
```

I do not want to disable Hardware Acceleration in my electron.js app.

How can I fix this error?